Create a Grid with a colorpattern that shows how many points are located per field in the grid
So i have an array of 168 X and Y coordinates. All of them are between 0 and 1. I would like to create a grid/mesh/heatmap that basically grids the arena into 0:0.05:1 fields and highlights through color how many of the points are located per field.
I know there should be an easy way to do this, but i havent figured out how to use heatmaps and somehow i cant wrap my head around it.
Thanks for the Time :)
I tried different approaches with pcolor, heatmap, gridmesh. but somehow i cant get it to run properly. Also im doing it in the app Designer and have an stl file in the background, just in case that changes things.
